# How to resolve overflow with widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow, flutter-layout

I have an image of an issue that is overflowing by 17 pixels.
& I'm unable to resolve it?
first of all, what I did..!!!

I took a `Row()`widget and wrapped with `Container()` &  in that `Row()` took two `Expanded()` widget. one is for  `TextField()` and another is for `CountryPickerDropdown()`.

[image]

I have used [country_pickers](https://pub.dev/packages/country_pickers) plugin

CODE:

```
 new Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)
                        ),  
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: CountryPickerDropdown(
                                initialValue: 'in',

                                itemBuilder: _buildDropdownItem,
                                onValuePicked: (Country country) {

                                  isCountryCodeSelected=true;
                                  print("${country.name}");
                                  print("${country.phoneCode}");
                                  print("${country.isoCode}");
                                  print("+${country.phoneCode}(${country.isoCode})");
                                 setState(() {
                                  countryCode= country.phoneCode;
                                });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none, 
                                hintText: "Telephone Number", 
                              ),

                              onChanged: (value){

                               setState(() {
                                 phoneValue=value; 
                               });

                                print("phoneNumbe:$phoneNo");
                                this.phoneNo = isCountryCodeSelected ? "+" + countryCode + value : "+91" + value ;
                                print("phoneNo="+phoneNo);

                              },

                            ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ),
```

Widget for Contry code and their national Flag image:

```
 Widget _buildDropdownItem(Country country) => Container(
    child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          CountryPickerUtils.getDefaultFlagImage(country),
          SizedBox(
            width: 8.0,
          ),
          Text("+${country.phoneCode}(${country.isoCode})"),
        ],
      ),   
  );
```

Comment: replace both `Expanded` with `Flexible`

Comment: I replaced it but nothing happend. The issue is still there as before, Overflowed by 17 pixels.

Comment: Try to use Expand widget with flex.

Comment: @AnkitGupta I tried but got exception and nothing is appearing on the screen.

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma Can you try taking 2 or 3 columns depending on the number of widgets you need to build the require UI inside the box.

Answer (score 4):

Suspecting that your countryselector widget needs to have expanded childs and the text overflow.

```
 Widget _buildDropdownItem(Country country) =>  Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Container(
             margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
             child: CountryPickerUtils.getDefaultFlagImage(country)),),
            Expanded(child: Text(
              "+${country.phoneCode}(${country.isoCode})",
                overflow: Overflow.Eclipse
            ),)
        ],

  );
```

Comment: `Eclipse` isn't supporting. getting error `The getter 'Eclipse' isn't defined for the class 'Overflow'`. then which library I have to import?

Comment: You can use any of the overflow types except for none, I was typing this in the browser without auto completion.

Comment: For word wrap, use TextOverflow.visible

Comment: overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the Expanded widget above the CountryPickerDropdown widget

If we set Expanded widget on both the child, Both will try to take the max width. So if we just set expanded widget on textfield only, textfield will take the remaining width of the screen. Below is the working code snippet with output of screenshot of small device.

```
Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          CountryPickerDropdown(
            initialValue: 'in',
            itemBuilder: _buildDropdownItem,
            onValuePicked: (Country country) {
              print("${country.name}");
              print("${country.phoneCode}");
              print("${country.isoCode}");
              print("+${country.phoneCode}(${country.isoCode})");
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "Telephone Number 14655656556",
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Wrap is replaced by Row and width of textfield reduced Hope this helps. Please let me know if something went wrong.

```
          new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(

                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(

                      child: CountryPickerDropdown(
                          initialValue: 'in',

                          itemBuilder: _buildDropdownItem,
                          onValuePicked: (Country country) {

                            isCountryCodeSelected=true;
                            print("${country.name}");
                            print("${country.phoneCode}");
                            print("${country.isoCode}");
                            print("+${country.phoneCode}(${country.isoCode})");
                            setState(() {
                              countryCode= country.phoneCode;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-30.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-30.0,
                      child: TextField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "Telephone Number",
                            ),

                            onChanged: (value){

                              setState(() {
                                phoneValue=value;
                              });

                              print("phoneNumbe:$phoneNo");
                              this.phoneNo = isCountryCodeSelected ? "+" + countryCode + value : "+91" + value ;
                              print("phoneNo="+phoneNo);

                            },

                        ),
                    ),

                  ],
                )
            )
```

The Wrap is replaced by Row and width of textfield reduced Hope this helps. Please let me know if something went wrong.

Comment: stiil getting overlapping error and after changing with your answer my widgets are appearing in column form.

Comment: Again edited by replacing `Wrap` with `Row` and resizing the `TextField`

Comment: Hey, it works on only larger screen, not on small screens. I still getting the overflowing error. see on link 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvEg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach ....(In the text field you can add your phone no and in the orange and cyan color flex you can add your country picker)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            body: SafeArea(
                child: Center(
                    child: Column(children: [
              Expanded(
                  flex: 25,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            flex: 1,
                                            child: Container(
                                              color: Colors.orange,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            flex: 1,
                                            child: Container(
                                              color: Colors.cyan,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: TextField(
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      ),
                    )
                  ])),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              )
            ])))));
  }
}
```

[image: In the text field you can add your phone no and in the orange and cyan color flex you can add your country picker]

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting you clearly. please code according to my code.

Answer (score -1):

```
Expanded(
                          flex:1  
                          child: CountryPickerDropdown(
                            initialValue: 'in',

                            itemBuilder: _buildDropdownItem,
                            onValuePicked: (Country country) {

                              isCountryCodeSelected=true;
                              print("${country.name}");
                              print("${country.phoneCode}");
                              print("${country.isoCode}");
                              print("+${country.phoneCode}(${country.isoCode})");
                             setState(() {
                              countryCode= country.phoneCode;
                            });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex:2
                          child: TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none, 
                            hintText: "Telephone Number", 
                          ),

                          onChanged: (value){

                           setState(() {
                             phoneValue=value; 
                           });

                            print("phoneNumbe:$phoneNo");
                            this.phoneNo = isCountryCodeSelected ? "+" + countryCode + value : "+91" + value ;
                            print("phoneNo="+phoneNo);

                          },

                        ),)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, getting exception. and nothing appearing on screen, after changing with your answer.

Comment: sorry, that Exception was not occurred by your answer. but still, your answer is not useful.